# iOS - Google ads issue with banner test not showing in my app only

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, google-ad-manager

maybe someone can shed some light on this...

I've been trying to implement Google ads on my app and it just doesn't want to work, no matter what I try.

This is the error I get on the test ID:

```
GADBannerViewDelegate - bannerView /6499/example/banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError 
Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 "Request Error: No ad to show." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., 
gad_response_info=  ** Response Info **
    Response ID: (null)
    Network: (null)

  ** Loaded Adapter Response **
    (null)

  ** Mediation line items **
}
```

I have tried the same GADApplicationIdentifier, same code, same pods versions for google ads, same type of ad size, etc, on the sample app, and the ad shows.

It just doesn't want to show up in my app (can't stress this enough, same code, I copy-pasted it to the sample and there it works)

Update: I have created a new project, using the exact same pods, plist properties and everything, and the ad shows there. I'm inclined to say that the issue is somewhere in the project configuration (project.pbxproj) or some other config... this is

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of reasons why your banner ad is not showing in your app.

1: Is your device registered as a test device in Ad mob?

2: Double check you are using the right identifier(s) in your info.plist. Triple check your ad id and GADApplicationIdentifier is correct as displayed in your ad mob account.

3: Have you completed all the necessary setup steps in ad mob? Not having a credit card on file causes issues.

4: Make sure you set up the app-ads.txt correctly for your account.

5: Has your app been released on the app store? If so make sure your ad mob account correctly reflects that and you have followed the steps for a production

Note if you have completed all the necessary steps it can sometimes take 72 hours for the ads to appear in your app.

Comment: I'm trying to just display the test ad "/6499/example/banner" for now, not even that works. And yes, all the above steps are good. The ad works on another sample app I've built, just the main app won't display it. "Request Error: No ad to show."

Comment: This is typical behaviour to be expected from Google. If all steps are completed then ads will be shown .... eventually.... sometimes even longer than 72 hours. The error is so general that so many possibilities could be causing it, even something to do with your account on googles backend you have no control over.